# How to make pdf from widget fit to screen when widget is Scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I'm successfully making a pdf with this sample code. It's making PDF from my Desire widget.
But if the widget is too long(Scrollable) then the image in pdf got small I have to zoom it to see the content...[smaple1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZV1d.jpg) If I do `fit: pw.BoxFit.fill` the widget in PDF got [squeeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xy4l.jpg).
Can I make the pdf fit to A4 size page, of just fit to screen or **Scrollable** pdf?

My function which making the pdf

```
final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> printKey = GlobalKey();
final doc = pw.Document();

void _printScreen() async { //=============> Pdf function
  final image = await WidgetWraper.fromKey(
    key: printKey,
    pixelRatio: 2.0,
  );

  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = File('${directory.path}/my_goal.pdf');
  
  final pdf = pw.Document();
   pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.FullPage(
      ignoreMargins: true,
      child: pw.Image(image, fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
      );
    },
  ));
  
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

  await Share.shareFiles(
    [file.path],
    text: 'Check out my goal details',
    subject: 'My goal details',
  );
}
```

calling the function to make and share pdf on button pressed

```
   IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                 _printScreen();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
```

Then wrap my desired widget from which I want pdf

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child:  RepaintBoundary( ||======>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>||
                key: printKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child:
                      Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
                      children: [
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultiPage`

```
 doc.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        build: (context) => [
          _createTitleHeader(context),
          //....
        ],
        pageTheme: pageTheme,
        footer: _buildFooter,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It woked a little but now its now showing `Widget won't fit into the page as its height (4751.0) exceed a page height (728.5039370078739). You probably need a SpanningWidget or use a single page layout`

`doc.addPage(
  pw.MultiPage(
    build: (context) => [
      pw.Image(image, fit: pw.BoxFit.cover),
    ]
  )
  );`

Comment: try to remove inner scrollable widget, treat it like column, once it get outof view, it will render on next page